# Finding primes $p$ such that $x+2$ is a factor of $x^5+3x^4+2x^2-5x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Find all the primes $p$ such that  $x+2$ is a factor of $x^5+3x^4+2x^2-5x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Solution: if $x+2$ is a factor then $-2$ is a zero of $x^5+3x^4+2x^2-5x+1$ by factor theorem.

Let $f(x)= x^5+3x^4+2x^2-5x+1$, so $f(-2)=0\pmod{p}$,
but $f(-2)=(-2)^5+3(-2)^4+2(-2)^2-5(-2)+1 = 35$ in the equation given.

I don't know what to do next to find all prime *p*, I hope you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: $35 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $p|35$?

Comment: No, but if $p|35=5 \times 7$.

Comment: since $35= 5 \times 7$, so are my primes are 5 and 7?

Comment: Yep! It appears so.

Comment: .thank you. now I get it